# Capistrano custom task calling git:create_release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I have created a custom capistrano task located in the lib/capistrano/tasks directory.

I have placed the task under a namespace. When I run cap -T my task appears in the list.

I want to call the git:create_release task inside my task. Currently I have:

```
namespace :setup do

  desc "Performs a setup"
  task :run do
    on roles(:all) do
      git.create_release
    end
  end
end
```

However, the above does not work. It gives me the following error:

> undefined local variable or method `git'

Now I assume the issue lies in not having some explicit import of the git submodules. I am not sure how to go about including them in the custom tasks module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `git.create_release` I think you need `invoke "git:create_release"`. See the [Capistrano README](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/README.md#before--after).